# How to change image href path inside fancyBox script

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, path, fancybox

I want to fix this but know very little about Javascript but need a site I'm working on finishing asap:

I want to change the href path pointing to an image inside fancyBox and 
Image Thumbnail Viewer II so that they point to two seperate images.

I have amended the other script as follows:

`'+"store-images/large_"+$anchor.attr('href')+'`

I have tried amending the following line amongst other things to no avail in fancyBox as follows:

`image    : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="store-images/full_{href}" alt="" />',`

I'm using one link for two functions and want to change the link slightly in the javascript to work with both.

Let's say the link shows:

`href="image-name.jpg"`

I want one link to end up showing

`="large_image-name.jpg"`

and the other to show:

`href="full_image-name.jpg"`

Here's the link to both scripts:

http://fancybox.net/

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/thumbnail2.htm

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, clicking the (already opened) image in fancybox, should link to another image, which its `href` is composed by the original `href` plus some additional parameters? Could you show the complete html you are using?

Comment: I've edited the OP to further explain things better, thanks!

Comment: I've tried adding the following script to the page to change the path of the clicked image to no avail as the content is added to the page once clicked, could this be modified to work with fancyBox?

`$('.fancybox-inner img').attr('src', function(index, Oldimg) {
return Oldimg.replace(/store-images\/large_/ ,'store-images/full_')
});`

Comment: to confirm : clicking where? on the link in your page OR on the image opened in fancybox

Comment: The link on the page.

Comment: I've read through my initial question and rephrased it in the hope that it might get me some more feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately is still unclear to me what you want to do, however if you have a link, which its `href` targets an image but fancybox should open another one, then you just need to compose the new target using the API option `href` inside fancybox http://jsfiddle.net/JEg2V/